# How do you make a button click event bring about random labels?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a project in which when the user clicks the button and a label becomes visible and I have 20 labels and I want to make it display labels randomly on each click

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. It is not clear what you are asking

Comment: Ok just help the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would first need to get all labels. This is the easiest using `LINQ`:

```
var labels = Controls.OfType<Label>().ToArray();
```

And then randomly make on of them visible:

```
var random = new Random();
var label = labels[random.Next(0, labels.Count - 1)];
label.Visible = true;
```

Comment: But it's showing system.windows............controlcollection does not define for 'OfType' help me

Comment: All the code should be together on the button click. For that you need to add `using System.Linq`

Comment: According to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) it does have `OfType`

Comment: So what do I do

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the entire file? It works if you did it correctly